# outlook vsto add-in can't find contact

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to find a given contact using email for search  `email` in a given folder `folder` using this method

```
    private static ContactItem FindContactByEmail(MAPIFolder folder, string email,string email2)
    {
        string filter = $"[Email1Address]='{email}'";
        $" used search filter [{filter}]".AddToLog();
        try
        {
            var result = folder.Items.Find(filter);// i tried folder.Items.Restrict(filter) too
            if (result!=null)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                $"can't find {email} at {folder.FullFolderPath}".AddToLog();
            }
        }
        catch(System.Exception r)
        {
            $"exception at FindContactByEmail {r.Message}".AddToLog();
        }
        // If the contact was not found in the current folder, search in its subfolders
        foreach (MAPIFolder subfolder in folder.Folders)
        {
            var contact = FindContactByEmail(subfolder, email,email2);
            if (contact != null)
            {
                return contact;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

i doubled checked that the contact exists in my folder but the method can't find it, it only find it at **Recipient Cache** folder missing all the contact details like phone numbers

Comment: Was the contact added from GAL? In that case, Email1Address will contain the EX type address, not SMTP.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes it is , so should i get the EX And use it in the filter as it is ? or should i change the [Email1Address]?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contact was created from a GAL entry, `Email1Address` will contain the EX type address, not SMTP. You can either:

1. Search for the EX address (`AddressEntry.Address` will give you that)
2. Search for the SMTP address specific property on the contact - `Email1OriginalDisplayName`. It is not directly exposed by the `ContactItem` object, but you can see it in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you click the Message button. It can be accessed in OOM through `ContactItem.Property.GetProperty`; the DASL property name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8084001F`. If you need to search against that property using `Items.Find/Restrict`, you need to use the @SQL syntax:

```
 string filter = $"@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8084001F""='{email}'";
```

Comment: the first solution works perfectly, I'm learning so I'll explore the second one too, Thanks!!. I see that you are the author of  Redemption too. I'm lucky having you to answer my question